# tf-idf, many docs, many terms

Tags: classification, text-mining, tf-idf

I have many documents and many labels. I would like to extract those terms that have a high tf-idf among the documents of a particular class. `tf-idf(term, doc, corpus)` scores a term for 1 doc compared to the corpus.

What would be a metric I can use across many docs (of the same class) `tf-idf(term, many docs, corpus)`? I would also like it to be quite efficient.

Comment: I probably didn't fully understand your question, if the document labels (topics?) are known to you, then can't you group documents by class  (union or average) and then use the "single-doc" tf-idf?

Comment: Neither am I able to fully understand your question; But if you want to extract terms that are relevant to one subset of your documents, but not the difference of that subset with the whole corpus, you can check out feature selection strategies (where the terms are your features). The simplest I can think of is Chi-square selection, for which there are several questions and answers here on CV.